# Why is it possible for a JvmStatic method to access and modify state?

Tags: kotlin, static-methods

I would've assumed that a method annotated with `@JvmStatic` would be unable to access, let alone modify, a class property.

Based on the following this is not the case. This code clearly updates state, printing `From main - 11`.

```kotlin
object Foo {
    var bar = 5

    @JvmStatic
    fun updateBar(updateVal : Int) {
        println("bar = $bar")
        bar += updateVal
        println("bar = $bar")
    }
}

fun main() {
    Foo.updateBar(6)
    println("From main - ${Foo.bar}")
}
```

Comment: `Foo` is an `object`, so there's only one instance of it.

Comment: `Foo` has state (`bar`), and that state is updated in a "static" method. This applies regardless of the number of instances of `Foo`.

Comment: @iluvfugu It doesn't apply "regardless of the number of instances of Foo": if `Foo` were a class, the method couldn't be marked `@JvmStatic`, and when it's an object, its state is "static"-like as well whether or not it's marked `@JvmStatic`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, sorry, I was not referring to `JvmStatic` or its applicability. I was referring to the fact that Kotlin objects have state.  Even if they are compiled to static Java code, single instance or not, they have state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also surprised by this. In fact, because `Foo` is an `object`, the field `bar` is actually a static field on the JVM.
That's why it's not a problem to access it from a static method.

The decompiled Java code of your class is the following:

```java
public final class Foo {
   private static int bar;
   public static final Foo INSTANCE;

   public final int getBar() {
      return bar;
   }

   public final void setBar(int var1) {
      bar = var1;
   }

   @JvmStatic
   public static final void updateBar(int updateVal) {
      String var1 = "bar = " + bar;
      boolean var2 = false;
      System.out.println(var1);
      bar += updateVal;
      var1 = "bar = " + bar;
      var2 = false;
      System.out.println(var1);
   }

   private Foo() {
   }

   static {
      Foo var0 = new Foo();
      INSTANCE = var0;
      bar = 5;
   }
}
```

However, I would avoid doing this. It's unexpected and doesn't really convey the intent.

Comment: If `bar` field weren't static, it could be accessed as `INSTANCE.bar` (and that's what I would have expected to happen).

Comment: Fait enough, but I still find it strange to read it this way instead of explicitly referencing the instance.

Comment: It seems strange to me that it's strange :) Enough that I wrote another answer.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you wouldn't be surprised without the `@JvmStatic` annotation; objects are allowed to have mutable state just as classes are.

But `@JvmStatic`/`@JvmField`/`@JvmOverloads` are all designed *not to change any behavior from Kotlin's point of view*, only the way it's exposed to Java. There is still a `this` inside the method (referring to the `object Foo`) just like there would be without the annotation. From [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods):

> If you use this annotation, the compiler will generate both a static method in the enclosing class of the object and an instance method in the object itself...
>
> Same for named objects:
>
> ```
> object Obj {
>     @JvmStatic fun callStatic() {}
>     fun callNonStatic() {}
> }
> ```
>
> In Java:
>
> ```
> Obj.callStatic(); // works fine
> Obj.callNonStatic(); // error
> Obj.INSTANCE.callNonStatic(); // works, a call through the singleton instance
> Obj.INSTANCE.callStatic(); // works too
> ```

The instance method obviously can manipulate the instance state; while the static method can simply call the instance one and be defined as

```
public static final void updateBar(int updateVal) {
    Foo.INSTANCE.updateBar(updateVal);
}
```

(even if according to @Joffrey's answer this isn't the way the current implementation works).

Comment: Good point about JVM annotations not changing Kotlin behavior

Comment: Okay, thanks for this.  That cleared things up a bit.